# Customize sign in

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

In login page I have two sign in tabs, Windows is for admins and Standard is for clients.
Currently it looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to customize them to look like this:

I want to make the Windows tab to look like a windows icon when this tab is not selected and make the tab as small as possible. ( icon name: mdi-microsoft-windows )

[image]

But when Windows tab is selected it should look like this:
[image]

This is the code that I have for login page:

```
<template>
  <v-main id="login">
    <v-container fill-height fluid>
      <v-layout align-center justify-center>
        <v-flex md4 sm8 xs12>
          <v-card class="elevation-12">
            <v-toolbar color="primary" dark>
              <v-toolbar-title>
                <v-icon left> mdi-login-variant </v-icon>
                {{ $t("welcome") }}
              </v-toolbar-title>
            </v-toolbar>
            <v-divider />
            <v-tabs v-model="selectedTab" grow hide-slider>
              <v-tab
                v-for="(tab, i) in tabs"
                :key="i"
                :class="{
                  'primary white--text': tab == selectedTab,
                  caption: tab != selectedTab,
                  boxShadow: tab != selectedTab,
                }"
                :href="`#${tab}`"
                class="pa-0"
              >
                <v-icon left v-if="tab === selectedTab"
                  >mdi-login-variant</v-icon
                >

                {{ tab }}
              </v-tab>
              <v-tab-item
                v-for="(tab, i) in tabs"
                :key="i"
                :value="tab"
                reverse-transition="scale-transition"
                transition="scale-transition"
              >
                <v-divider />
                <v-card-text>
                  <v-form @submit.prevent="login">
                    <v-text-field
                      v-model.lazy="username"
                      :label="$t('username')"
                      :prepend-inner-icon="
                        tab === 'Windows'
                          ? 'mdi-microsoft-windows'
                          : 'mdi-account'
                      "
                      :rules="[username !== null || required]"
                      name="username"
                      class="windows"
                      outlined
                      placeholder=" "
                      type="text"
                    />
                    <v-text-field
                      v-model.lazy="password"
                      :label="$t('password')"
                      :rules="[password !== null || required]"
                      name="password"
                      outlined
                      placeholder=" "
                      prepend-inner-icon="mdi-lock"
                      type="password"
                    />
                    <!-- If error, rended error component -->
                    <error-view
                      v-if="error"
                      :error="error"
                      :is-login="true"
                      class="pa-0"
                    />
                    <v-card-actions class="pa-0">
                      <v-spacer />
                      <v-btn :loading="loading" color="primary" type="submit">
                        {{ $t("submit") }}
                      </v-btn>
                    </v-card-actions>
                  </v-form>
                </v-card-text>
              </v-tab-item>
            </v-tabs>
            <div id="version-div">
              <app-version />
            </div>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-main>
</template>

<script>
import AppVersion from "@/components/version";

const errorView = () => import("@/components/errorView");

export default {
  name: "Login",
  components: {
    errorView,
    AppVersion,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      tabs: ["Windows", "Standard"],
      selectedTab: "Standard",
      username: null,
      password: null,
      loading: false,
      error: null,
      required: (value) => !!value || this.$t("req"),
    };
  },

  methods: {
    resetForm(value) {
      this.username = this.password = value;
    },
    login() {
      if (!this.username || !this.password) {
        this.error = this.$t("warn");
        this.resetForm(null);
      } else {
        this.loading = true;
        const encodedPass = window.btoa(
          unescape(encodeURIComponent(this.password))
        );
        this.$store
          .dispatch("retrieveUser", {
            username: this.username,
            password: encodedPass,
            outside: this.selectedTab === "Windows" ? false : true,
          })
          .then(() => {
            this.$router.push({ name: "home" });
            this.error = null;
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            this.error = error;
          })
          .finally(() => {
            this.resetForm("");
            this.loading = false;
          });
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.boxShadow {
  box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 30px 60px -12px inset,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 18px 36px -18px inset;
}
</style>
```

I tried multiple ways to do it by maybe creating two separate tabs and then applyig the logic so that it works the same as in the first picture, but nothing that I do works. Would love all the help that I can get. Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: You don't want any icon when windows tab is selected ? or you just want to increase the width of the windows tab when selected?

Comment: @skr When windows tab is not selected it only shows the misrosoft windows icon, but when it’s selected it doesn’t show the icon but only the text - “Windows”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `v-else`, it depends up to you what you want to display when user clicks on standard tab you show icon as well as a simple element.

`<v-icon left v-if="tab === selectedTab">with Icon</v-icon>`

`<v-icon v-else left >with Icon and style you want to apply</v-icon>`

**or**

`<v-icon left v-if="tab === selectedTab">with Icon</v-icon>`

`<p v-else left >without Icon or style you want to apply</p>`

**Update**

As you asked, how to style the element, well there are multiple ways:

Suppose you added this element:

`<v-icon v-else-if="tab == 'Windows'"> mdi-microsoft-windows</v-icon >`

you can simply use **`style`** attribute

`<v-icon style="height:10px;width:10px" v-else-if="tab == 'Windows'"> mdi-microsoft-windows</v-icon >`

**or**

you can define a class attribute:

`<v-icon class="windows" v-else-if="tab == 'Windows'"> mdi-microsoft-windows</v-icon >`

and in the css section in your vue file, you simply style your element like below

```
<style>
.windows{
height:'';
width:'';
color:'';
background-color:'';
}
</style>
```

**Update:**
`max-width: fit-content;` is what you are looking for.

SandBox - https://codesandbox.io/s/red-glade-wzgbd?file=/src/components/Playground.vue

Comment: @Goldy Updated my answer with styling elements, check that out.

Comment: try your css with `!important` this should override the any css applied to particular element. check this out https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp

Comment: try to override them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234645/discussion-between-skr-and-goldy).

Comment: Can you check this if this is what you are expecting? https://codesandbox.io/s/red-glade-wzgbd?file=/src/components/Playground.vue